# What's the difference between these two IIFE invocation syntaxes?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
(function f() {
    // do something
}());
```

vs

```
(function g() {
    // do something
})();
```

*Note the position of the ending parentheses.*

1. Do these execute in the same manner?
2. Do they restrict the scope of variables differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. Just two notations to do the same thing. 
Some people find one notation more intuitive than the other. Just a matter of preference, nothing more than that.